# Is bctls (Bouncycastle TLS) on maven?

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I wanted to use Bouncycastle's TLS implementation in my Java project. Somehow it seems as if bctls (bctls-jdk15on:156 is the latest release) is not on the maven repo.

I have checked mvnrepository.com as well as google without any luck.

Does anyone maybe knows not indexed repo which has this lib? Is there any other alternative than installing the jar locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, it is on Maven central. You can find it under [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bctls-jdk15on). Unfortunately, 1.56 does not seem to be indexed. If you must use 1.56, I would contact the mailing list and see if they could add it.

Comment: thanks it seems that they added this library starting with version 1.57. So i could not find it as 1.56 was the most recent version back then. Thanks for answering this question tho. Now i know it for the future.